# Can I exclude hosts from a Knife SSH run within a Chef environment?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

My issue is, I want to run:

```
knife ssh "chef_environment:env1" 'cmd'
```

but one of the hosts is having auth issues, and seems to be breaking my knife ssh run, and not running the command on all hosts. I would like to exclude the one host from being run when using environments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

`knife search "chef_environment:env1 AND NOT name:foo"` but beware that `NOT` queries can be *super* unintuitive because of how Chef searches work.